# Why does my animated gif not show up in mobile browsers, even with cleared caches, but only on Opera Desktop?

Tags: html, embed, gif, animated-gif, webflow

So i've been trying to get this gif to animate, it needs to be placed as an HTML embed, rather than uploading to webflow, to get around file size restrictions, otherwise the quality of the image is far too low to be usable.

I've tried running a  tag when I had the transparent .webm and .mp4, and had this same problem.  So I thought "well, if I'm just using an html embed, what's stopping me from embedding an animated gif? Nothing." so I uploaded my animated gif to google cloud, and linked it using an  tag and it showed up fine in the Webflow designer.  Shows on preview mode, even shows up when published! Huzzah! My default browser is Opera, however, I understand that's not many people's default.  So I open in Brave, Chrome, Firefox...and all of these are -not- showing the gif! There's just an empty space!

I go to inspect element, and set it to display device as "iPhone 12 Pro" and it looks good there for Opera, but even when I use an actual iPhone and look at it, on Opera or any of the aforementioned browsers for mobile, and it's not showing.

I don't get it.

`<img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/babyganimation/Main%20Composition.gif">`

Like there's my code.  That's it.  As basic as can be.  No styling or anything yet, just trying to get this cocksucker to work.  It's been so frustrating, this is siiimple siiimple HTML stuff they teach on your first day of class.

Like whyyyy?

I tried adding it as a basic img tag or using video formats, as a video tag. I tried variations such as using the "type=" command and still nothing.

I don't get it.